# Python: Why is my for loop not iterating over the entire list?

Tags: python, list, debugging, for-loop, iteration

So I have an "Object Class" that looks like this (details abstracted away for readability)

```
class Object: #this is a generic object: the player, a monster, an item, the stairs... it is always represented by a character on the screen.
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    #Default Variables
    self.always_visible = False
    self.blocks = False
    self.inventory = []

    for k, v in kwargs.iteritems():
        setattr(self, k, v)

    if TexturePack == True:
        self.color = libtcod.white

    #Components
    #if self.fighter:  #let the fighter component know who owns it
    try: self.fighter.owner = self 
    except: self.fighter = None

    #if self.ai:  #let the AI component know who owns it
    try: self.ai.owner = self 
    except: self.ai = None

    #if self.item: #let the Item component know who owns it
    try: self.item.owner = self
    except: self.item = None

    #if self.equipment:  #let the Equipment component know who owns it
    try: 
        self.equipment.owner = self
        #there must be an Item component for the Equipment component to work properly
        self.item = Item()
        self.item.owner = self
    except: self.equipment = None
```

and I am creating a monster with this code

```
            #Create Goblin
            fighter_component = Fighter(hp=10, power=8, defense=0, xp=10, death_function=monster_death)
            ai_component = BasicMonster()
            monster = Object(x=player.x+3, y=player.y, char='g', name='Goblin', color=libtcod.lightest_green,
                blocks=True, fighter=fighter_component, ai=ai_component)

            #Populate Goblin's Equipment
            monster.inventory = [
                Object( x=0, y=0, char='-', name='Dagger', color=libtcod.cyan, equipment=Equipment(slot='right hand', power_bonus=2) ),
                Object( x=0, y=0, char='!', name='Light Healing Potion', color=libtcod.red, item=Item( use_function='cast_heal( "Potion", player.fighter.max_hp/6, player)' ) ),
                Object( x=0, y=0, char='$', name='Scroll of Chain Lightning', color=libtcod.yellow, item=Item(use_function='cast_lightning( player, damage=20, sRange=5, chainLength=3 )') )
            ]
            for item in monster.inventory:
                if item.equipment:
                    item.equipment.equip()
```

then I am trying to make it drop all of its items in this function.

```
def monster_death(monster): #consider letting a monster keep it's char but change the bg and the char to red.
    #transform it into a nasty corpse! it doesn't block, can't be
    #attacked and doesn't move
    message( monster.name.capitalize() + ' is dead!', libtcod.orange)
    monster.char = '%'
    monster.color = libtcod.dark_red
    monster.blocks = False
    monster.fighter = None
    monster.ai = None
    monster.name = 'remains of ' + monster.name
    monster.draw_last()
    for element in monster.inventory:
        if element.item:
            element.item.drop()
```

What is happening is; it is iterating over all but one of the items in the inventory list but not the entire list. (I know from debugging one of the items stays in the inventory list and doesn't drop)

also; here is the drop function in the item class if this helps.

```
def drop(self):
        for object in objects:
            if self.owner in object.inventory:
                if self.owner.equipment:
                    self.owner.equipment.dequip()
                #add to the map and remove from the player's inventory. also, place it at the player's coordinates
                objects.append(self.owner)
                object.inventory.remove(self.owner)
                self.owner.x = object.x
                self.owner.y = object.y
                if object == player:
                    message('You dropped a ' + self.owner.name + '.', libtcod.yellow)
```

I am having really hard time trying to crush this bug...any help is appreciated. :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your *minimal and complete* code.  With the quantity of undefined terms in this posting, we can't give you effective help.

Comment: Also, give us the debugging output you've generated so far.  If nothing else, there should be **print** commands to trace execution.  For instance, does the iteration actually identify each item?  *Which* item remains in the inventory?  If it's the first or last one, you have an obvious culprit in the initialization or termination.

Comment: A minor style point: don't use "object" as an index variable, since "object" is the name of a built-in class.  You can get surprising bugs that way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is both too much and not enough code there, to be able to find the "actual" problem. I would guess, though, that you are probably iterating over a list or array or collection and simultaneously removing things from it. That's a common question here on SO.

In general, you will see weird behavior like skipping over elements, or (in your case) having a list that should be empty show up as not empty.

In particular, I see you in one function doing this:

```
for element in monster.inventory:
```

In another function, you are doing this:

```
for object in objects:
    ...
    object.inventory.remove(self.owner)
```

I wonder if the `monster.inventory` list and the `object.inventory` list aren't the same at some point, which gives you a function accessing the list via an alias and removing elements, while you are trying to iterate over the list elsewhere.

Here's an example:

```
>>> inventory = [1,2,3]
>>> for item in inventory:
...     print(item)
...     inventory.remove(item)
...
1
3
>>> inventory
[2]
```

What happens is the iterator (for item in inventory) points to [1], the [1] gets .removed(), which means the iterator now points to [2], which is the new "first item" in the list. The loop finishes, the iterator advances, and now the iterator points to [3]. The [3] gets .removed(), the iterator tries to advance and reaches the end of the list, so it stops. You have now removed the [1] and the [3], and skipped over the [2].

Making a copy of the list, then iterating the copy, will ensure you iterate over every single item, while removing them from the official list.

Comment: You were right...I was iterating over a list and removing elements from it at the same time...I fixed the issue by deleting the 0th element in the list until the 0th element was nil. :)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like in the first object:

```
Object( x=0, y=0, char='-', name='Dagger', color=libtcod.cyan, equipment=Equipment(slot='right hand', power_bonus=2) )
```

You don't declare the **item** attribute, so the following loop:

```
for element in monster.inventory:
    if element.item:
        element.item.drop()
```

the *if* clause interprets **item** as *False* and skips the first element.

If some exception is occurring in the initialization method of class *Object* (and catched) the attribute **item** will not exist causing the error.

Comment: Unless there is something else declaring an `item` attribute, this could definitely be the cause. Since it seems like the `item` attribute is being used to describe on-use behavior, this conditional should probably be skipped all together.

Comment: look at the object class...the object class always assigns an item class as self.item = Item() if there is an equipment class.

Comment: So the same thing happens when I remove the if statement.